# Deleting rows in excel based on comparison (python, pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

i have been trying to compare two files and delete rows from file2 based on the comparison. i want to keep the row in file2 if the value exists in both files under "Category 2". if the value from file2 doesn't exist in file1, delete the row. i have been looking into concatenation and deleting non-duplicates, but i assume there's a more logical approach to this? i also can't find anything specific to comparing dataframes and deleting rows that are NOT common. i'm mostly finding things that delete duplicates, etc. any pointers or new direction to solving this would be appreciated. thank you

also, if it makes sense to delete any headings in file1 like "All Lists" or other categories to make things easier, i wouldn't mind that either.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

#df1_i = df1.set_index(['Category 2'])
#df2_i = df2.set_index(['Category 2'])

output = df2[(df2['Category 2'].isin(df1['Category 2']))]
output
```

current output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Manager]
Index: []
```

file1

```
All Lists
Category 1  Category 2  Category 3  Category 4  Category 5  Category 6                   
List 1                  
            element1        x   
            element2        x   
            element3        x   
            element4        x   
            element5        x   
List 2                  
            card1           x   
            card2           x   
            card3           x   
            card4           x   
            card5           x   
List 3                  
            box1            x   
            box2            x   
            box3            x   
            box4            x   
            box5            x
```

file2

```
Category 2   Manager     quarter1    quarter2    quarter3    quarter4                total
element2       A           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement     B           $          $           $           $                      $
card3          C           $          $           $           $                      $
box4           D           $          $           $           $                      $
element3       E           $          $           $           $                      $
box1           F           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement     B           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement     C           $          $           $           $                      $             
card7          D           $          $           $           $                      $
element4       E           $          $           $           $                      $
```

desired output:

```
Category 2   Manager     quarter1    quarter2    quarter3    quarter4                total
element2       A           $          $           $           $                      $
card3          C           $          $           $           $                      $
box4           D           $          $           $           $                      $
element3       E           $          $           $           $                      $
box1           F           $          $           $           $                      $
card7          D           $          $           $           $                      $
element4       E           $          $           $           $                      $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.isin`:

```
df1_i = df1_i.reset_index()
df2_i = df2_i.reset_index()
output = df2_i[(df2_i['Category 2'].isin(df1_i['Category 2']))]
output
```

Comment: do you mind looking at the updated post to see the output? i got rid of the categories in file2 to test things out, but as you can see, the results doesn't put anything out besides an empty dataframe and the headings of file2.

Comment: @J.Doe try resetting the index as shown in my edited answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Also, you've probably created sample data for your stackoverflow post, but it does not appear to line up with the columns, as I don't see any column `Title` in the output data lower in your post.